# Firmware Bug on Boot Up Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, firmware

I am seeing the following bug every time I boot up my system.  The system will successfully boot, so it seems to recover from it - but I am chasing down other odd system behaviors and wonder if this error is contributing to other, downstream errors.  Error message is:

```
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xdc923000-0xdc923fff flags 0x200] vs dc923000 4000
Kernel Device: +acpi:MSFT0101:00
```

Comment: You may need to update your BIOS. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for a newer BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Some kernel messages may appear on boot.

It is a sort of a bug itself that worries many newbies for many years. On some Ubuntu releases they do appear with some GPU drivers, on some they don't.

To my opinion something is to be done to remove these messages when Ubuntu boots into GUI. But Ubuntu maintainers don't really care, because this doesn't affect anything.

If you run `dmesg`, you'll see a lot more messages to think about. ;-)

Regarding this specific message you can disable TPM in your BIOS. But generally there is nothing to worry about.

See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1431165&sid=0c0d6958b1c3b5546b8cccae8b992d63#p1431165